# Why are AngularJS modules called apps?

Tags: angularjs

I started learning AngularJS today and I am a bit confused about modules (angular.module(...)).

Why are AngularJS modules called apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, angular modules aren't called apps. Sometimes you can see an "app" or "myApp" module (i.e. in official docs). It's just a convention. It means the main module of your web app.

Some projects consist of only one module - then name "myApp"/"app" kind of makes sense. That's the case in most examples in official documentation, thus they use name like "myApp".

Answer (score 0):

They're not. They're called modules. There's typically a distinction made that your main module (that executes the core functionality of your application) is your app, but that's just a convention made to help people understand the layout of the modules.